# Android OpenGL ES 1.1 poor performance under ICS - eglSwapBuffers taking 60+ms

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, frame-rate, tegra

I am currently working on an opengl ES 1.1 game, min sdk 8, target sdk 17 and I am seeing an unusually large delay in eglSwapBuffers on the 4.0.3 tablets I have access to that does not appear on either newer or older versions of android. I'm also lucky enough to have access to two Asus transformers T101's, one of which is running Honeycomb so can rule out that this is a limitation of the hardware.

The Following table shows a number of devices, and their performance.

```
Model           OS      FPS     Max/avg eglSwapBuffer time (ms)
Acer A500       4.0.3   12.5    70 /67
Asus T101       3.1     21.8    30/21
Asus T101       4.0.3   12.2    79/65
HTC One X       4.0.4   35.9    14/5
Nexus 7         4.1.2   35.6    16/5
Samsung GTP1000 2.2     24.5    36/28
```

You can see that even the ancient single core GTP1000 gets double the framerate of the dual core 4.0.3 devices.

I am running 4 threads,A 2D Canvas, GL, UI and a heartbeat that updates AI every 200 ms. During eglSwapBuffers calls on the GL thread the the CPU is doing pretty much nothing. It feels like I'm triggering some sort of power save or GPU throttling but I haven't been able to find any information about this.

The time taken in swap buffers alone limits the frame rate to <15FPS if all other operations cost nothing. I am drawing 150 textured triangle strip quads per frame.

If you can point me in the right direction I'd be thrilled, I've been banging my head against a brick wall for the better part of a week.

Comment: Do you have android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in your manifest? See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I don't have it in there in the tests above, since it isn't supported in 2.x. I had tried it previously and have since re enabled to no significant difference. (0.02 FPS well with in the margin of error)

Comment: Why you use OpenGL ES 1.1? Since your min sdk is 8 OpenGL ES 2.0 is supported. "OpenGL ES 2.0 provides faster graphics performance than the ES 1.0/1.1 APIs". See this link for more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html#choosing-version

Comment: We will probably be moving to ES2 at a later date, project has been in development for 2.5 years, back then es 2 support wasn't a guarantee and original scope was much smaller with a much shorter time span.

Comment: Not an answer really, but are you sure you're only benchmarking the swapBuffer call?  Basically, you get no guarantee of when calls are executed, so the time it takes to execute swapBuffer might include the execution time of other stuff being executed.  Useful link (about Direct3D but related nonetheless): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172234(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Have you tried removing the targetSdk setting?   I know it should be there and really shouldn't break anything.   I also know I had to reissue my app on the store because adding it unexpectedly slowed everything down on some devices (including T101 4.0.3).